# Uipath two decimal places

Tags: vb.net, uipath

I need  to format my double value for example "12.4" into "12.40" , and "1" to "1.00" and I was searching for a function in the internet for a whole hour and can not find, or there is any other way to fix it? Everything must be seen in .xls file.

Comment: And you haven't see the ToString and the [standard numeric format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings)?

Comment: @Steve, I have used math.Round(Double.Parse(taxDataRowItem),2), but it prints without zero at the end

Comment: When you say "Everything must be seen in .xls file," do you mean that all the decimal places should still be visible in some Excel file or that you need two decimal places displayed in Excel? For the latter, you need to set the cell formatting in Excel to "0.00".

Answer (score 0):

VB.NET has several functions to format a decimal as a string.

```
Dim integerNumber As Integer
integerNumber = 17843
Console.WriteLine(integerNumber.ToString("F", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
' Displays 17843.00
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings